# Passing parameters to fmincon with lb and ub

Tags: matlab

I have a working script with fminsearch as shown below:

```
[t,fmin] = fminsearch(@fun,t0,[],x1,x2,x3,...,xn);

function error = fun(t,x1,x2,x3,...,xn)
```

I have to pass quite a few parameters to the function fun to get the t array containing two values, t(1) and t(2).  I learned that, though, fminsearch doesn't work with constraints, but I have a constraint: lb <= t(1) & t(2) <= ub.

I've been reading about fmincon, but I haven't yet found an explanation to both pass additional parameters and set constraints.

What is the syntax of using fmincon with a simple inequality constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fmincon (and other optimization functions) if you don't use some  constraint parameter, you just put [].

Other thing you should check for is that some function receive row vector and other column vector.

For 3x1 vector function:

```
options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','interior-point','Display','final');
 [xfmincon,fval,exitflag,output] = fmincon(fh3,[0;0;0],[],[],[],[],[-10;-pi;-10],[+10;+pi;+10],[],options)
```

1) To handle other variables you split the main function to 2 functions, one that will use all params, and one that you will pass to fmincon:

```
fh3main=@(v,param1,param2) v+param1*sin(v)+param2; 
fh3=@(v) fh3main(v,myparam1,myparam2);
```

2) The constraints are easy to handle, they have same size as input vector, and you can assign same values or different values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  My question was more about: 1) where and how I can pass x1, x2, x3,..xn parameters from my script to fmincon and 2) I want to apply lb and ub both to two variables, t(1) and t(2) (or three in your example).  For the constraint application, maybe lb and ub automatically apply to all variables?  Then, I just need to know the syntax for additional parameters.

Comment: Thank you again.  Can you clarify a couple of things for me?  I am very new to anonymous function and still can't understand the syntax.  Between fh3main and fh3, param1&param2 are essentially same as myparam1&myparam2, right?  For fh3main, in my case, it's a .m file instead of an inline function.  In that case, do I write it this way: fh3main=@(v,param1,param2) myfun(v,param1,param2)?

Comment: 'myparam1' is  input argument that will called 'param1' in receiving  function. And of course, you can use regular m file function instead of anonymous.